# opacity of textview in android

Tags: android, textview, opacity

In my application, initially I'm setting opacity of `TextView` to 60.
After that, when the user presses a button, I want to decrease or increase the opacity of the `TextView` as per pressing in a button that increases it or a button that decreases it.
I have tried this, but every time when I get the opacity of text view its -3 or -1 which is actually not.

```
 public void decreaseOpacity(View v){

    int op=txtView.getBackground().getOpacity();// its alwz -ve value
    txtView.getBackground().setAlpha(op-1);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawable.getOpacity() dos not take into account changes made by setAlpha(). [See the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getOpacity%28%29):

> Note that the returned value does not take into account a custom alpha
>   or color filter that has been applied by the client through the
>   setAlpha(int) or setColorFilter(ColorFilter) methods.

You may need to store the alpha value as a variable and not use getOpacity(), on example:

```
private int mTextViewAlpha = 255;

public void decreaseOpacity(View v){
    if ( mTextViewAlpha-- <= 0 ) mTextViewAlpha = 0;
    txtView.getBackground().setAlpha(mTextViewAlpha);
    txtView.getBackground().invalidateSelf();
}
```

Comment: I've added simple example. Please note that I've not compiled it, so typos are possible ;)

Comment: Changed the `>=` to `<=`, so it might work better now. Like he said, typos are possible.

Comment: Yyp, thanks Geobits :) Plus, I've added invalidateSelf() call to force background redraw. Now I've confirmed it works. If you want for the background to become transparent more quickly, subtract more than 1 from the mTextViewAlpha.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
public class AlphaTextView extends TextView {

  public AlphaTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public AlphaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public AlphaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) {
    setTextColor(getTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
    setHintTextColor(getHintTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
    setLinkTextColor(getLinkTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
    return true;
  }
}
```